# Displaying a specific count of items in a horizontally scrollable parent in different screen sizes

Tags: reactjs

I want to write a react component which receives the number of items that should be visible in the scrollable parent and regardless of screen size (in my case md and upper sizes), it must always display that count of items and others should become visible by scrolling. Here is my code but it doesn't work and more than desired count of items get displayed. In other words, I want to limit the number of items visible in the scrollable parent for example by 12 items. I use MUI by the way.

```
//My component
const AppCarousel = ({ numVisible, items, itemTemplate }) => {
    return (
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Grid container wrap="nowrap" sx={{ overflowX: 'scroll' }}>
                    {items.map((item, index) => (
                        <Grid item xs={12 / numVisible}>
                            {itemTemplate(item, index)}
                        </Grid>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
};

export default AppCarousel;

//The item that should be rendered inside the parent several times
const carouselItem = (item, index) => {
        return (
            <Button
                onClick={() => (item.status.toLowerCase() == 'done' ? onGetAttempt(item, index) : '')}
                sx={{
                    backgroundColor: !item.select ? alpha(pack.primary_color, 0.2) : pack.primary_color,
                    borderRadius: `${borderRadius}px`,
                    border: `2px solid ${pack.primary_color}`,
                    py: 1.5,
                    opacity: item.status.toLowerCase() !== 'done' ? 0.3 : 1
                }}
            >
                <Typography variant="h5" textAlign={'center'}>
                    Attempt-{item.attempt_number}
                </Typography>
            </Button>
        );
    };

//I call my component this way inside its parent component
<AppCarousel numVisible={12} items={attempts} itemTemplate={carouselItem} />
```